# How to convert a ArrayList of Objects into List of Integer in java

Tags: java, spring

I used this native query to fetch data. 
`select c.id,c.name from customer c,information i where i.status=1 and c.id=i.customerId`

and  i used the below code to convert the object list into integer list as

```
public List<Integer> getAllIdsByGroupId(Integer groupId) throws Exception {
    List<Object[]> list = repository.getAllIdsByGroupId(groupId);
    List<Integer> ids = repository.mapIds(list);
    return ids;
}


public List<Object[]> getAllIdsByGroupId(Integer groupId) {  
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select c.id,c.name from customer c,information i where i.status=1 and c.id=i.customerId and c.groupId=:groupId");
    query.setParameter("groupId", groupId);
    List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();
    if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return list;
}


public List<Integer> mapIds(List<Object[]> list) {
    List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
        Integer id;
        for (Object[] object : list) {
            id = (object[0] != null ? (Integer) object[0] : null);
            ids.add(id);
        }
    }
    return ids;
}
```

The query retrieves a list with id and name.and the above code gives output without exception.But i require List with only ids.    when i remove c.name from query as follows
`select c.id from customer c,information i where i.status=1 and c.id=i.customerId`
 the above code fails and produce the exception

```
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Any helps? thanks in advance.

Comment: *What* object list? Is this SQL? A native query from a JPA provider? OrientDB?

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: It looks to me like your `list` is already a list of `Integer`s.

Comment: Good point. Try changing the type to `List<Integer>`.

Comment: can u tell the 'list ' variable is in which type

Comment: I edited the  above code .variable list is a ObjectList

Comment: Perhaps try showing us what kind of object you plan on passing into this method?

Comment: Does `object[0]` pass the `instanceof` test?

Comment: object[0] is to get c.id and object[1] is to get c.name. however i get the answer.  thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the typecasting
Change
`List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();`

to
**`List<Object> list = query.getResultList()`**

It is list of object where as your code is trying to convert and integer into List of Array.

`List<Integer> list = query.getResultList()` will also suffice if you are just trying to get ids

Comment: It will not work if select statement contains several columns like in above case (id, name). And for single column cases List<Integer> should run without problem - no need to assign result list firstly to List<Object> then iterate through the whole list again in order to convert Object to Integer.

Comment: @ZaurGuliyev i have answered based on the query raised by the submiitter which says " i require List with only ids. when i remove c.name from query as follows
select c.id from customer c,information i where i.status=1 and c.id=i.customerId
the above code fails and produce the exception

java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;" he just needed id and wanted to know why the Code was throwing ClassCastException

Comment: there's no need to cast result you get from query.getResultList() to List<Object>, which already returns List<Integer> in selects with single expression (check general rules in my answer). The correct code is: List<Integer> list = query.getResultList();

Comment: Ok thanks Zaur Guliyev. if there are several coulmuns as in the above case , this code will work fine.

Comment: @Tom I've explained every detail in your issue, but you've accepted answer which was not complete and even wrong from professional point of view, and user has updated his answer based on provided corrections. Anyway, Good luck! :)

Comment: @ZaurGuliyev the user has accepted the answer which helped him solve the problem, I updated the answer so that it can be more generic,Also as your answer does not say why there was a classcastexception,I am not here to win the war of points by getting my answer updated.I have just answered the question based on the issue.

Comment: @ZaurGuliyev also i would like to know how the answer is wrong from professional point of view?Please do not misguide

Answer (score 2):

If you're using JPA / Hibernate for fetching single column data then it returns `List<Integer>` implicitly (based on type of that column), so no need to convert it to Integer list.

**General rule:**

- If you are selecting an entity, then result is list of that entity typed items
- If you are selecting primitive, then result is list of that primitive wrapper typed items
- If you are selecting multiple expressions (id, name), then result is Object[] containing the corresponding primitives/entities

Comment: how can i assign object list into integer list

Comment: Just use List<Integer> not List<Object> - it should work as a general rule - updated my answer and included other rules.

Answer (score 0):

try this one may not try in my editor but may i thing one of this solution help you.

```
public List<Integer> mapIds(List<Object[]>  list) {
    List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if(list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
        int id;
        for(Object[] object : list) {
            id = (int) (object[0] != null ?  object[0] : null);
            ids.add(id);
     }
 }
 return ids;
}
```

Comment: it gives the same exception. it works fine when the query retrieves both c.id,c.name. and fails when it retrieves c.id only

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is lacking a lot of information, the most likely reason for the `ClassCastException` is that you're trying to cast objects that are not of type `Integer` to type `Integer`. I'm not sure what's in the list that you're passing into the method, but if the list does indeed contain some objects of type `Integer`, then what you could try is to check for that before converting element `object[0]` into `Integer`,

```
public List<Integer> mapIds(List<Object[]> list) {
    List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
        Integer id;
        for (Object[] object : list) {
            id = ((object[0] != null && object[0] instanceof Integer) ? (Integer) object[0] : null);
            ids.add(id);
            }
        }
    }
    return ids;
}
```

However, if the objects in `list` don't contain any `Integer` objects, then the only way to achieve what you're doing is to initialize an `Integer` object for each `object[0]` by somehow retrieving the `int` value in each. Only you know how to do this.

Comment: it gives the same exception.